# 7-zip -xr!*.bat is creating an empty archive with the batch files name

Tags: batch, 7-zip, exclude

I am trying to exclude files from a 7-zip batch.

The syntax is:

`for %%A in (*) do  "C:\Program Files\7-Zip\7z.exe"  a  -tzip -xr!*.docx "%%A.zip" "%%A" -xr!*.bat`

The command is creating zip files of all the files in the folder including the `*.bat` files but the `*.bat.zip` files are empty.

Is there any way to stop the empty files from being generated?

Answer (score 0):

First, I assume there's a `*.*` in the parentheses, and that you are generating one zip per input file.  If that's not the case, you might need to change the below.  I got empty `.bat.zip` files using:

```
for %%A in (*.*) do "C:\Program Files\7-Zip\7z.exe" a -tzip -xr!.docx "%%A.zip" "%%A" -xr!*.bat
```

7-zip creates the archive before adding files, so you get an empty archive even if nothing is going to go into it.  To fix that, check the file before adding it to an archive:

```
@echo off
for %%A in (*.*) do call :doit "%%A"
goto end

:doit
if "%~x1"==".bat" goto :eof
if "%~x1"==".docx" goto :eof
if "%~x1"==".zip" goto :eof
"C:\Program Files\7-Zip\7z.exe" a -tzip %1.zip %1 
goto :eof

:end
```

(tested on Windows 7).

The `for` loop now calls the "doit" subroutine, which starts at the `:doit` label and exits on any `goto :eof` command.  The `goto end` after the `for` loop just jumps over the subroutine for a clean exit.

The `if` statements exclude the files you don't want archived.  `%1` is the filename to test, and `%~x1` is its extension.  If the extension is undesired, `goto :eof` returns to the `for` loop and 7-zip is never called.

The 7-zip command no longer has the `-x` flags, since you know the filename is good when you hit the 7z command line.  There are no quotes around the `%1` since it was already quoted in the `call` statement.

Hope this helps!

Comment: When performing the `if` test for the file extension in the sub, I would add the `/i` flag to ignore case. Otherwise, files that have extensions with mixed- or upper-case would get added to the zip.

Comment: Thanks for the information.  I will try this.  As for the /i, I have no idea where to put it.  This is all new to me and I have been trying to understand the program so I know what it is doing. Is there anyone who might be able to interpret what is happening?  I have a batch that will zip the files in a folder and then will zip the subfolders into individual files so I get an easy to manage archive with PW protection and encryption.  The only problems I have been having are the exclusions and figuring out how to have the files created in a folder "d:\testfolder"

Comment: This is the syntax of my batch... 
for %%i IN (*.*) DO d:\portable\7z\7za.exe -t7z a -mx9 -pPASSWORD "%%~i.7z" "%%i"  pause  for /d %%X in (*) do "d:\portable\7z\7za.exe" -t7z a -mx9 -pPASSWORD "%%X.7z" "%%X\
pause
I put in the pauses so I could view the messages and errors after it ran. Still working on markup.

I do not understand what is happening.
If someone could break down the script for me, I would appreaciate it.

BTW, I know what -mx9 and -t7z -p are doing but that is about it.  I came here because most of the command line info I have found was here.
Any hlp would be appreciated.  
MP